# Disable Google Chrome password bubble for WebDriver tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Given the following code snippet:

```
 case "CHROME":
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", DriverPaths.CHROMEPATH);
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
     options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
     options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
     options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
     options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
     options.addArguments("--no-proxy-server");
     options.addArguments("--enable-automation");
     options.addArguments("--disable-save-password-bubble");

     Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
     prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
     options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
     return new ChromeDriver();
```

Why am I still seeing:
[image: password bubble]

And:
[image: infobar]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know the up to date chrome option to disable the password bubble? Tried everything you listed here and we still get it!

Comment: @GrayedFox the accepted answer worked for me. What version of Chrome and Chromedriver are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use the following commands:
options is your chrome options.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

By passing the capabilities to the chrome driver they will be loaded into chrome.
The `DesiredCapabilities.chrome();` will select the correct browser, in this case Chrome.

Comment: this method does not appear in class ChromeOptions? I am using Java not C#

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I updtated my answer

Answer (score 0):

> Chrome asks for the password when your account is set for autologin.
>   Doing this makes it so that the keyring doesn't load when you
>   reset/reboot your system.
>
> Chrome is asking for the password to the keyring so it can access
>   stored information in the keyring. You can view the keyring on your
>   system by running the command seahorse from a terminal window. You can
>   also just bypass the asking by closing the window and still get to
>   your sites without a problem. Some of the security may not load
>   properly.
>
> However, you can use the following command from a terminal window to
>   bypass the keyring asking:
>
> ```
> google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic
> ```
>
> Hope this helps!

YOU CAN SET IT FOR YOUR CHROME LAUNCHER TOO

*Courtesy of @Terrance*